# 3D Deconvolutional Layer

Tags: neural-networks, mxnet-format

I noticed that one of the mxnet APIs (Gluon) includes a [3D Deconvolutional Layer](https://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/api/python/gluon/nn.html#mxnet.gluon.nn.Conv3DTranspose). However, mathematica currently only allows up to 2D deconvolutional layers ([see here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConvolutionLayer.html)). Can one somehow implement a 3D Deconvolutional layer directly from mxnet (for example with the `NeuralNetworks'MXLayer` function)?

EDIT: Is it possible to implement n-dimensional convolutional layers in a similar way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following solution using convolutional layers and reshape layers on the community page:

https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1344787